# Wooden recorder services in Sydney

Tags: maintenance

I need someone to replace the cork on my wooden descant recorder and can't find anyone to do it in metropolitan Sydney.  Does anybody have a recommendation? I am not desperate enough to post it off because I am sure my recorder would be lost.

Comment: Hi there - welcome to Music.SE. Your question isn't one that's on topic here, I'm afraid. Worthwhile contacting other local recorder players, I would suggest.

Comment: Are you sure you need the cork replaced?  The life of the cork can usually be extended by carefully heating it with a flame to expand it.